# iOS 4.0 v 4.2 AdMob Issue: Attempt to run on device breaks on ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios-simulator, admob

I am working on iOS app with Google AdMob SDK 3. The AdMob SDK contains the following code:

```
kADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait =
    &ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait != nil ?
    ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait :
    ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
```

I understand that ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50 is deprecated in iOS 4.2 and later. I need my app to be compatible down to iOS 4.0.

When I build this code against iOS 4.0 SDK on the simulator, all goes fine. When I build against iOS 4.0 for device, I get the following error:

```
'ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait' undeclared
```

Why is this? I understand that AdMob implemented this code specifically to get around the issue of ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50 being deprecated in favour of ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait.. so why doesn't it work? Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say you build "against iOS 4.0", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I mean build with a base SDK of 4.0.

Comment: That's what I suspected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build with your "Base SDK" set to 4.2 or higher ("Latest iOS" will work) and your "iOS Deployment Target" set to 4.0 so it will run on your phone. Setting the "Base SDK" to 4.0 will not work, because those symbols are not defined in SDK 4.0.

Comment: until you run it on the simulator running 4.0, in which case it crashes.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: That's what weak linking and checking if the symbol is non-NULL are for. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html) for details.

Comment: yeah, but in this case it is easier to either ignore the deprecated warning, or check the version.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: Not really. But I'm not going to argue it with you here.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Xcode 4.5. They have moved the declarations and you now need to add the line:

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using Xcode 4.5 i have same problem what u mentioned above.

after i added  #import  this header file i am facing another issue below here

ld: warning: ignoring file /Development/stalin/Working/ComicsheadLite1.5/iAd.framework/iAd, missing required architecture i386 in file /Development/stalin/Working/ComicsheadLite1.5/iAd.framework/iAd (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait", referenced from:
      -[P_ExpressViewController addBannerView] in P_ExpressViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ADBannerView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in P_ExpressViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)